# Secure applications on Windows?

Tags: windows, drm, copy-protection

The Sony Playstation 3's in-built DRM/Copy Protections makes it a very attractive platform for developers (less piracy) same perhaps with iPhone. I believe this is achieved by virtualising the OS, sandboxing the applications. Can we have that security on Windows? are their any plans or means?

Comment: iPhone isn't safe, it's just not really worth it to hack. Apps are so cheap and it's a pain to use something like Hackulous.

Comment: Yeah, I think online, integrated app-stores make buying easier than pirating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 has it's own Apple-style App-Store, the 'Windows Store'. Bringing the 'walled garden' approach to Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Attractive for developers it may be... but it stirred quite a bit of controversy, and has not been in the news for some time now... was/is codenamed Palladium, aka Trusted Computing

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-Generation_Secure_Computing_Base

Comment: tried to be as neutral as possible in the answer :P but I'd love to say: who needs another vendor-locked walled garden? Thats never going to work on a computer (and in fact Apple is not doing anything like this on their computers)... at least, I hope so!

Comment: I totally agree...the worst case scenario of Palladium is that a company can dictate what is 'trustworthy' software and lockout everything else. Not a goal to go for.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, however massive piracy makes it likely I'll go broke struggling on making old-fashioned desktop software. All the growth is in online apps, which I feel ambivilant about re responsivness (lack of). Continuing what I'm doing feels like a thankless uphill battle, while I watch online software like WOW creaming huge profits.

Comment: @Jeff McClintock: Don't get me wrong...but unlicensed software copies are, imo, a pushed problem. Most people who have them wouldn't buy the software/game anyway. I mean, how many of the pirated Photoshop-Copies out there would have been bought if there would be no other way? How many of the pirated PC games would have been bought? Don't get me wrong (and I don't wanna insult you or something, hell no), but maybe if no one wants to buy your software, maybe it is your price/performance ratio or your software itself. But I should really stop here...this is getting way to off-topic... :/

Comment: The same old Bullshit! I hear this from every download kiddie.
Fact: The pirated version of my software was released March 2010. Sales next month were suddenly down 72%! "wouldn't buy the software anyway" yeah right... Anyway. Excuse my emotion, but I've heard all the excuses already. Anyhow, I asked a technical question, about trusted environments.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research:
Next Gen Secure Computing base - appears to be dropped. No activity on their blog for years.
Paladium (Microsoft-specific version of Next-Gen) - Likewise dropped, lives on perhaps in the xbox trusted environment.

Windows 8 - "A new "Windows Store" is perhaps the most ambitious feature described. Microsoft would offer a store service to third-party software developers. The store would handle standard features like account management and software updates, as well as providing capabilities such as the ability to replicate applications and settings across different devices. The store would be curated, so only applications that reached a certain quality standard would be permitted. The basic model, then, is a cross between Apple's App Store and Valve's Steam.".
 Steam is a DRMed platform, limited mostly to games though. Perhaps we are getting a similar system after all.